# Angular scope not updating after orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-orderby

I'm building an angular component that renders a table, and I'm running into some issues with the sorting function. The scope in this case looks like this:

```
$scope.listState = {
    sortBy: '<string>',
    sortReverse: <bool>,
    headings: {...},
    list: [
        {
            rowCols: {
                user: 'timfranks@gmail.com',
                name: 'Tim Franks',
                since: '11/6/12'
            }
            rowState: {...}
        },
        {
            {
                user: 'albertjohns@sbcglobal.net',
                name: 'Alber Johns',
                since: '11/12/13'
            },
            rowState: {...}
        },
        {
            {
                user: 'johnsmith@sine.com',
                name: 'John Smith',
                since: '7/28/14'
            },
            rowState: {...}
        }
    ]
};
```

I originally tried to sort the list via:

```
ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.list | orderBy:$ctrl.listState.sortBy:$ctrl.listState.sortReverse"
```

This didn't work, although in tracing with the debugger I found that orderBy was in fact getting the right arguments and returning a properly sorted list. Just to be sure, I changed the code to use orderBy in my controller, like this:

```
this.listState.list = _this.orderBy(listState.list, 'rowCols.' +  listState.sortBy, listState.sortReverse);
```

This works for the first time (called within the constructor), but then stops working. I'm pretty sure this is some aspect of Angular's scope that I don't fully understand. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify exactly what you would like to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue was that I used an attribute directive to render the list rows, and the attribute directive and `ng-repeat` were on the same element. This created a scope conflict between the two directives. I moved my directive to a div within the `ng-repeat` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using a filter in an `ng-repeat` expression **does not update the original model**, but rather creates a copy of the array.

You are on the right track with the `this.listState.list = _this.orderBy(...)` ... and it does make sense that it gets called only once.

If the `listState.list` model is getting new values after the controller loads and you want to resort with those new values, you would probably want to use something like:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('listState.list', function listChanged(newList, oldList){
    $scope.listState.list = _this.orderBy(...);
});
```

I can't recall if `$watchCollection` is going to register a change if the order changes, but if you end up in an infinite loop with that code, you could put a blocker like:

```
var listSorting = false;
$scope.$watchCollection('listState.list', function listChanged(newList, oldList){
    if(!listSorting){
        listSorting = true;
        $scope.listState.list = _this.orderBy(...);
        $timeout(function resetSortBlock(){ // try it without the $timeout to see if it will work
            listSorting = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer lead me to remember that ng-repeat creates its own scope, which helped me work out the problem. Thank you!